# Relative clause/Relativsatz

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, relative-clause

What happens in German if I have a relative clause like these ones?

> We have been playing with a ball, that our neighbour planned for ages to buy.
>
> This is the house, which I dream of living in.

I mean somehow an indirect object that I need to refer to. Literal translation is not as important as clearing the concept. So, please only one sentence (relative clauses) for each is allowed.

Comment: Well, it’s possible to construct these sentences in most cases, but they are unidiomatic. This construction is quite popular in Latin, so a search for [relativische Verschränkung](https://www.google.com/search?q=relativische+Verschr%C3%A4nkung) turns up lots of hints on how to reformulate them.

Comment: Would you provide an example for that? 
Examples for relativische Verschränkung are mostly in Latin and I did not study Latin

Comment: You would sometimes use adverbs to replace a verb, e.g. _in dem ich **gern** wohnen möchte_, or split a sentence into multiple so that you can use demonstrative pronouns instead of relative pronouns to refer back to something.

Comment: I am not convinced that the second sentence is correct English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "We have been playing with a ball, that our neighbour planned for ages
>   to buy"

```
Wir haben mit einem Ball gespielt, den unser Nachbar schon seit Jahren
zu kaufen plante.
```

Ohne Ball und Nachbar zu kennen kann ich nicht sagen, ob es um einen Ball von einer besonderen Art geht, oder ob es um ein spezielles Exemplar geht, ein Unikat. Falls es kein Unikat ist, sondern ein besonderer Typus:

```
Wir hatten mit einem Ball, wie ihn unser Nachbar schon seit Jahren 
zu kaufen plante, gespielt.
```

> "This is the house, which I dream of living in."

```
Dies ist das Haus, von dem ich träume, darin zu leben.
```

Da das darin Leben die übliche Verwendungsform für Häuser ist, wäre hier ein einfaches

```
Das ist mein Traumhaus.
```

wohl gleichbedeutend und die naheliegende Formulierung.

Comment: Zu ersterem, nein. "Wir haben mit einem Ball gespielt" NICHT "Wir hatten..." das wäre "We had been playing". Ich weiß, in Deutschland verwendet man "hatten" und generell Plusquamperfekt viel öfter, richtig ist es dennoch nicht.

Comment: @Teolha: Geht auch: "Wir spielten mit einem Ball, wie ihn unser Nachbar ... zu kaufen plante."?

Comment: In der "angewandten Sprache" verschwindet die Grenze zwischen Perfekt und Imperfekt ja zusehends. Imperfekt wird im Alltag heutzutage viel seltener benutzt. Dennoch wäre die wörtliche Übersetzung von "We have been playing" ins Perfekt zu setzen, d.h. "Wir haben gespielt". Stünde da "We played", dann wäre das Imperfekt und im Deutschen "Wir spielten". Allerdings sind meine Aussagen mit Vorsicht zu genießen, ich bin nur Hobbyist und Muttersprachler, was die deutsche Sprache anbelangt, kein Experte. :)

Comment: Zu dem "wie ihn unser Nachbar"... ja, wäre durchaus möglich. Allerdings wäre es wieder "Wir haben mit einem Ball, wie ihn unser Nachbar..." Generell klingt es mMn aber unrunder. Da steckt irgendwie etwas implizites darin, so à la ", von dessen Machart unser Nachbar" und das klingt noch grausiger. Kann nicht sagen woran genau es liegt, ist wohl nur persönliche Präferenz.

Comment: Danke für eure Kommentare. Ich wollte halt das Konzept von indirekten Objekten sozusagen in einem relativen Satz nachvollziehen.

Comment: "have been doing" means someone started the action in the past, and is still doing it in the present.
Ich würde sagen, das passt besser zu dem Präsens, aber ich bin kein Deutch Experte.